# Substitute for MySQL's UUID Version 1 function?

Tags: php, mysql, uuid

**Context**

Web application, PHP 5, MySQL 5.0.91

**The Problem**

I recently switched from using an auto-incremented integer to a UUID as a primary key for some of my tables. When generating UUID's via MySQL's [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function, they are extremely similar to one another:

```
| uuid                                 |
----------------------------------------
| 1e5988da-afec-11e1-9877-5464f7aa6d24 |
| 408092aa-afad-11e1-9877-5464f7aa6d24 |
  ^------^   ^^
  1      8   11-12
```

As you can see, only the first 8 characters and the 11th and 12th are different. I understand that UUID Version 1 uses a timestamp and hardware MAC address to generate the UUID. However, I am hesitant in using Version 1 because of these similarities (and the fact that the MAC address will never change, in my case). In addition, if the MAC address never changes, most of the UUID is useless and is wasting space.

**My Custom UUID Function**

As an experiment, I wrote a custom UUID-generator in PHP:

```
public static function GenerateUUID()
{
    return
    substr(sha1(Account::GetUsername() . Account::GetUserID()), 18, 8) . "-" .
    substr(md5(time()), rand() % 28, 4) . "-" . 
    substr(md5(date("Y")), rand() % 28, 4) . "-" . 
    substr(sha1(rand()), 20, 4) . "-" . 
    substr(sha1(rand() % PHP_INT_MAX), 17, 12);
}
```

A sample of the results:

```
| uuid                                 |
----------------------------------------
| 574d18c2-5080-bac9-5597-45435f363ea1 |
| 574d18c2-30d4-8b5b-4ffd-001744d3d287 |
```

Here, the first 8 characters are identical for the same user. This was intended, but not needed.

**The Question**

Is there a preferred/recommended way to generate a Version 4 or Version 5 UUID *within a MySQL query*?

If not, is it acceptable to generate a custom UUID within PHP (as above) that does not conform to a specification?

**Restrictions**

- I am using a shared hosting plan with command-line access, but cannot modify the existing MySQL installation.
- I would prefer avoiding third-party packages/libraries.

**Notes**

- I do not and will not be performing merging, synchronization, or other operations that require a GUID that contains the MAC address. That is not the issue here.

Comment: Just to understand better, why did you stop using auto numbers and have you considered making some sort of SHA? Also, there is UUID_SHORT()

Comment: @MatthewRiches: `UUID_SHORT()` is not available in MySQL 5.0.X (I clarified the version in my question). I decided to switch from an auto-incremented integer after reading http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html.

Comment: As a sidenote: "if the MAC address never changes, most of the UUID is useless and is wasting space", this is wrong, the MAC address hash is critical if you want to do multi-server synchronization.

Comment: @AlixAxel But I don't, which is why the MAC address will never change.

Comment: @EvanMulawski: I get that, but if you ever do, MAC address will come handy. =)

Comment: @AlixAxel As stated, I am on shared hosting (1and1), so I have neither the need nor the ability to perform db syncing.

Comment: @EvanMulawski If you don't need multi-server sync, use a x-bit pure random GUID, **don't** use a UUID just for the sake of using it.

Comment: @Pacerier Could you describe what a "x-bit pure random GUID" is and how I can use it?

Comment: @EvanMulawski Unlike UUID which follows some kind of "format", a purely random GUID simply uses any arbitrary number as the primary key. So if you are looking for a 128-bit pure random GUID, simply generate a random 128-bit value and use it as your primary key. If it that value already exists, generate another one.

Comment: Strictly speaking, neither example random UUID is valid. The first digit in the third group of numbers must be the UUID version number: i.e. `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` for version 4 (random). There are also restrictions on the first digit of the fourth group. See Wikipedia for details.

Answer (score 11):

Your concern, that "most of the UUID is useless and is wasting space" is inherent to the size of the data type.
You will never be able to have as many entries in your database, as the theoretical limit of 16 bytes allows.

In fact, V1 UUID is more fit than V4 if you use the UUID just as a table ID - because it uses MAC-address and time stamp to prevent clashes. In V4 there is no such mechanism, although practically you don't need to worry too much about clashes either :)
You should use V4 UUID instead of V1 if you need your UUID to be unpredictable.

Also, note that composing for example 4x4 byte random values may not be the same as creating a 16 byte random value.
As always with crypto and randomness: I would disadvise from implementing your own UUID::V4 routine.

If installed on your machine, you can make use of the `php-uuid` package.

<s>An example code (which can be used in your application as is) can be found here:
http://rommelsantor.com/clog/2012/02/23/generate-uuid-in-php/</s>

Use it like this:

```
$uuid = uuid_create(1);
```

Users that are are able to install packages on their webserver, can install the required package, like: (here for ubuntu)

```
apt-get install php5-dev uuid-dev
pecl install uuid
```

Comment: as times are a changing ... I wonder what impact the movement to random MAC addresses adds to the picture (e.g. Apple's randome MAC address mobile strategy to increase anonymity for their mobile phone users from iBeam and sniffer sensors).  I would think with all the devices, all the manufacturers, and the number of random instances over time ... while the numbers are big, the argument of Version 1 being guaranteed unique is now eroding.  A lot has changed over four years which leads us to need to think more about what 'could' happen versus where we are today.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually a fairly good idea to appreciate having the "similar parts".  It will allow you to leverage the MAC address to be able to identify "which of my servers generated this UUID?"... which will be extremely helpful when migrating data between remote locations.  You can even do "this is my test data" and "this is my production data" this way.

PHP has a large number of UUID-generator libraries.

Here's one PECL/PEAR thing (I never used it):

http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid

From the CakePHP framework:

http://api.cakephp.org/class/string#method-Stringuuid (cake 2.x)
http://api13.cakephp.org/class/string#method-Stringuuid (cake 1.3)

Last generator option:

Consider using a Linux command-line `uuid` program, which would have the `-v` version control flag and related options, and using that to feed your database. It's sort of inefficient, but at least you won't have to write up your own generator functions.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/uuid - man page

(package `uuid` for Debian)

I noticed that for the namespace versions, you'll be generating lots of "long human names" to convert into uuids.  As long as you don't have conflicts with those, it might be very sweet.  For example, users registering with e-mail addresses... Get v5 uuid for that e-mail address... you'll always find that person! It seems to spit out the same UUID each time, and the UUID will represent the unique relationship bob@bob.com has with example.com, as a member.

`uuid -v5 ns:URL "http://example.com/member/bob@bob.com/"`

Commentary:

Also, UUIDs, the way you seem to be storing them, are CHAR(36)? You might regret that once comparison operators kick in.

Postgres will treat UUID as 128-bit values (and presumably do optimized binary operations), whereas MYSQL's CHAR(36) solution is looking at 36 bytes = 288-bits ANSI or 576-bits UTF8 plus-or-minus bits/bytes for office-keeping (and presumably do much slower multibyte-char-by-multibyte-char string routines).

I've actually put a lot of consideration into the issues for MySQL plus UUID... and my conclusion was that you'd want to write up a stored function that converts the hex representation into the binary representation for storage, and that would make all "select" statements require a conversion back into hex representation... and who knows how efficient any of that will be... so finally just switch to Postgres. XD

If you do want to switch to Postgres, try be very careful about installing it on your existing server(s) if they are production servers. As in... make a clone to test the migration process before actually doing a migration. I somehow managed to kill my system because of "installing this package will remove a large number of important other packages" (I don't know how the installer made those decisions).

Alternatively, go with Microsoft SQL for their GUID equivalent, if you're prepared to eventually pay them lots of money to operate a DB...

Doing UUID and MySQL just tends to be a bad idea at the moment.

Comment: Oh...? After seeing the comment @matthew-riches UUID_SHORT() is kind of cool for the 90+% of the operators that need small scale uniqueness... I'd still want an integer based 128-bit UUID generator built-in.

Comment: I just clarified the exact version in my question. `UUID_SHORT()` is not available in MySQL 5.0.X.

Comment: The cost of doing UUID as CHAR(36) is ridiculously high, and becomes stupid at 1+ milion, 10+ million, 100+ millions of rows, in my humble experience.  It would be somewhat more cost-effective to use clustering and redundancy than to do mysqldump backups at those levels of "number of simple uuid rows" and "number of compound uuid-foreign-key'd relationships"

Comment: You should be storing a UUID as BINARY(16) - I've never tried myself using a UUID column as primary key in MySQL but I'd assume it'd handle binary keys as efficiently. Annoyingly this means hex-parsing the output of `uuid()` into binary e.g. [function to do that](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,49626,51650#msg-51650)

Comment: You can use the `uuid=UNHEX(REPLACE(?,"-",""))` as a means to convert the string to a binary version. No need to write a stored procedure there.

Comment: Neat. It occurs to me now that both of those get the bytes in the wrong order, but as long as you parse a newly generated UUID only and you're not trying to store an existing UUID then it's fine.