# Using UUID in CakePHP, What DataType Is Recommended?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, cakephp-2.0, uuid

My Scenario:

- New Cake (2.x) Project, No DB Yet
- MySQL Clustered, and maybe Oracle Clustered Prod
- No DATA needs to be migrated/imported
- Data can look like: `Users` -> HABTM -> `Groups` -> HABTM -> `Other Groups`

I've been doing a little research on how to use UUIDs with CakePHP, and I have found the following:

Cake has Native Support for UUID, but it assumes `CHAR(36)`:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

This [Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10918405) points out that:

> The cost of doing UUID as CHAR(36) is ridiculously high, and becomes
>   stupid at 1+ milion, 10+ million, 100+ millions of rows, in my humble
>   experience

This [Blog Post](http://www.paulmarshall.us/blog/cakephp-and-uuids) claims that `BINARY(36)` is better than `CHAR(36)`:

> Although CakePHP does not support the 16 byte hex encoded UUID with
>   the key type of BINARY(16), it does support BINARY(36) which is still
>   better than using CHAR(36) which can be slowed down by collation.

...but the Cake Docs don't say that...

My Question is, given CakePHP/MySQL (or CakePHP/Oracle), is CHAR(36) the only reasonable choice here, or is there a better, more efficient way to use UUIDs with CakePHP (or any other PHP Framework for that matter)?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use `innodb` then your primary key will be appended to **every** index and you'll have a **significant overhead** in indexes size. Generally the smaller PK data type is - the better. And personally - I prefer to always use integers for it.

Comment: Agreed on the overhead, but unfortunately for the records that this app is creating they need to be globally unique, which does affect performance.

Comment: I agree, BINARY is way more performant than CHAR, the 3.x way is documented here: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/blob/3.0/docs/Features.md#uuid-as-binary36

Comment: `BINARY(16)` is even more performant but the trouble with need to explicit `hex`ing and `unhex`ing the value in DB will make you avoid it. By the way, an old blog post that mentioned a quick benchmark of `CHAR(36)` vs `BINARY(16)` is [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/03/13/to-uuid-or-not-to-uuid/) and I believe `BINARY(36)` will lie somewhere between those two; possibly more towards the good side ;)

Comment: @mark the link is dead now, are there any alternative sources maybe?

Comment: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/blob/master/docs/Database/Uuid.md probably
But I think it is also already natively in core ( https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/11297 )

Answer (score 4):

You probably already know this, but you could generate an id with `String::uuid()` for new records, and have `BINARY(16)` in your table - I don't think cake has any automagic past the uuid generation.

Comment: Yeah, my app is now doing this for new records and this strategy works for the time being.

Comment: **I don't think cake has any automagic past the uuid generation** CakePHP can generate and generate and use a `uuid` for primary key field as per the docs. Although, they mention about `CHAR(36)` as the column type in DB is supported out of the box, I really doubt `BINARY(36)` will work without a shim or workaround. A small note of interest is [here](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/blob/master/docs/Features.md#uuid-as-binary36). In general, a discussion on this topic happened almost 3 yrs after your answer on [github](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6393)

Comment: It's `BINARY(16)` or `CHAR(36)`, UUID is 128bit value 128/8=16 bytes, optionally encoded as 36 characters (8+4+4+4+12=32 + 4 separator chars)

Answer (score 2):

If CakePHP is given a model with an id field whose SQL type is Binary(36), then every time you create new records, the id field will be given a new GUID value. This behaviour is here since version 1.3.15.

Regarding your other issue, since CHAR involves collation, I would go for the binary solution.