# php-mysql how to increment a binary, UUID primary key and get inserted id

Tags: php, mysql

how to autoincrement a binary column .and how to get the mysql_insert_id/last insert id...
i am doing like this

```
$on="INSERT INTO `public_poll`(`poll_id`,`poll_closing_date`,`active`)
VALUES((select UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''))),(select DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)),1)";
 $onj=mysql_query($on);
```

but how to get the inserted id

Comment: Please, can you provide your table definition?

Comment: Assume public_poll( poll_id BINARY_BLOB, some_date DATE, active BOOL ).  We only care about poll_id here.

Comment: BINARY_BLOB? Isn't just BLOB?

Comment: @hdvianna poll_id is a binary field and my primary key .i want to autoincrement that field .and need the inserted id .

Comment: @starlocke the database is already there with binary 16bit..

Comment: @hdvianna -- whatever, it's pseudo schema.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I thought you were working with an AUTO_INCREMENT field.

Now that I notice that you're using a UUID field stored as a binary, I'd recommend that you move to Postgres, instead.

Basically, you don't ever want to "autoincrement" UUIDs, because, that simply produces mangled UUIDs.  You see, the theory behind UUID inserts is that you *absolutely shouldn't* fetch an ID *after* its insertion; instead, you should have generated the UUID in the original app, and remembered it there -- PHP, in this case.

Personally, on a Linux system, I simply `exec()` against libuuid (sp?) and use that value all over the place.

There also exists various UUID libraries for PHP, like this thing: http://pecl.php.net/package/uuid

Edit: More info here: [Substitute for MySQL's UUID Version 1 function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917613/substitute-for-mysqls-uuid-version-1-function/10918405#10918405)

Comment: @user2215270 -- I answered your question quite directly, didn't I ?  Are you saying I went on the wrong path, somehow, because you used "but" in there ? /confused/